Issues with regard to moving SES out sandbox so that Cognito authentication can be ready for new user regsitration
I made my first attempt trying to move my account out of SES sandbox, because I need to get my Cognito userpool ready for new users signup, but within 24 hours the request was rejected. Here is the message I wrote AWS Support.
Hello,

We [name_of_my_company] is building a community-based iOS application that focuses on enhancing the well-being of our user. The product introduction can be seen on our landing page[domain_name.com].

The primary reason that I am sending this request of moving my account out of sandbox is that I need to turn on Amazon SES to get ready for new user registration through AWS Cognito. We need to activate Amazon SES because we are planning to get new users in the coming weeks. Email will be the mean by which new users receive their verification codes when they sign up. At this stage, we are not using AWS SES for marketing purposes. Our platform, therefore, do not need services that cover features such as bounce, complaint and unsubscription.

The current draft of the email template would be something like the following,
Hello [username],
Your verification code is [verification_code_from_cognito]. This code will expire in [amount_of_time] hours.
Warm regards,
Moof Team

If you require any extra information from us, we will be happy to facilitate.

Thank you.

I guess the reason my request was rejected was because I did not answer the question "tell us how you manage bounces, complaints, and unsubscribe requests". At the current stage, I am not using SES for marketing purposes, so I dont really see how bounce, unsubscription and complaints could be a potential issue for my request. My question is, how I should frame my message if I need to get SES out of sandbox so that my coginto userpool can accept email addresses from new users?
